# Can you return a variable out of a listener in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, return, listener

I am struggling to find a solution to proceed with my program when a listener completes.
So my main goal is it to `return` a queryParameter of the DeepLink that leads back to my app. I already found out how to get the params with [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links) :

```
String function(){
   linkStream.listen((String? link) async { 
      if (link!.startsWith(redirectUri)) {
        param = Uri.parse(link).queryParameters['code'].toString();
        print(param);
      }
   });   
}
```

But now I want to `return param` instead of just printing it into the console. The problem is, because the return type of a listener is `Future<void>`, I am not able to just return the String without some kind of a workaround.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: check `Stream.map` / `Stream.asyncMap`

Comment: could you give an example? I am really stuck on this.

Comment: check https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams or just https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods